# not getting results in django search

Tags: python, django, search, pagination

I created a simple django blog where i want to provide a search option. so , I tried and didnt even get any error.

but the problem is I didn't even get any search results too. its showing empty page even if there is a post related to that query. help me out guys.

Here my code goes......

views.py

```
class home_view(ListView):
    model = home_blog_model
    template_name = "home.html"
    context_object_name = "posts"
    paginate_by = 8
    ordering = ['-date']


def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get("key")

    if query:
        results = home_blog_model.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query))
    else:
        results = home_blog_model.objects.filter(status="Published")


    return render(request , "home.html" , {"query":query})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView , LogoutView
urlpatterns = [

    path("" , views.home_view.as_view() , name="blog-home"),
    path("posts/<int:pk>/" , views.detail_view , name="detail"),
    path("admin/login/" , LoginView.as_view(template_name="admin-login.html") , name="admin-login"),
    path("admin/logout/" , LogoutView.as_view() , name="admin-logout"),
    path("admin/post/create/" , views.create_post_view , name="create_post"),
    path("post/search/" , views.search , name="search_post"),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class home_blog_model(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

home.html

```
<div align="right">
    <form class="form-group" method="GET" action="{% url 'search_post' %}">
        <input type="text" name="key" placeholder="search........" value="{{request.GET.key}}">
        <button class="btn" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning the results from the `search` view. The context you pass only contains the query.

Also, in `home.html` you're not iterating over the results, in an attempt to display them.

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: You can find more information in part 3 of Django tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/

Comment: i have carefully read your answer again and applied...and guess what it worked like a charm.

Comment: i wanna say thank you very much. god bless you genius